# ArcGIS Pro - Labels inside polygon a set distance from boundary

Tags: arcgis-pro, labeling, dictionary, maplex

I am using an abbreviation dictionary with my labels, however sometimes the label is too close to the polygon boundary so I'd like to set a "distance from the polygon boundary" threshold that the label will conform to or it will either decrease in size or use the abbreviation (set by the strategy order).  I tried using the "measure offset from the feature geometry" but I don't see any difference. Am I doing something wrong or is there no way to do this?

Comment: Seems to work for me? I did play around with setting the offset units to "Map Units", have you tried that?

Comment: yeah.  I don't see any change.  Some of them are ok but then others are literally right on top of the boundary line